# Update multiple meta_value with single query

Tags: mysql, update, mysqli

Here is a similar structure of a table that I am working on.

```
|--ID--|--user_id--|--meta_key---|--meta_value--|
|--1 --|--444444---|--first_name-|------NULL----|
|--2 --|--444444---|--last_name--|------NULL----|
|--3 --|--444444---|--phonenum---|------NULL----|
|--4 --|--333333---|--first_name-|------NULL----|
|--5 --|--333333---|--first_name-|------NULL----|
|--6 --|--333333---|--phonenum---|------NULL----|
|--7 --|--222222---|--first_name-|------NULL----|
|--8 --|--222222---|--first_name-|------NULL----|
|--9 --|--222222---|--phonenum---|------NULL----|
```

I am trying to `UPDATE` all the info for a given user. Let's say I want to update the `first_name`, `last_name`, and `phonenum` for the user with `user_id` `333333` in a single query using mysqli.

This is not a wordpress database, so please do not include native wordpress functions in the answer.

Comment: Can you always guarantee that the fields are the same and in the same order - i.e. first_name, last_name and phonenum are always the same, always adjacent and there only ever will be 3 records in the table for a given user_id. By "adjacent" I mean that the IDs will be consecutive?

Comment: @Vérace no, unfortunately there is no guarantee that will happen.

Comment: Can one at least assume that the number and name of fields will remain the same - if not in sequence with ID?

Comment: You have found one of many reasons why a key-value schema sucks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but it won't fit in a comment, so please excuse me in advance. Maybe you'll find the approach of help - I'm stuck!

I was working on something along these lines - but it depends on the adjancy that I refererred to earlier on - maybe the selects could be varied to get the right data?

```
CREATE TABLE My_Table
(
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT,
  meta_key VARCHAR(15),
  meta_value VARCHAR(15)
);


INSERT INTO My_Table (user_id, meta_key) VALUES(44444, 'John');
INSERT INTO My_Table (user_id, meta_key) VALUES(44444, 'Doe');
INSERT INTO My_Table (user_id, meta_key) VALUES(44444, '12345');
INSERT INTO My_Table (user_id, meta_key) VALUES(33333, 'Mary');
INSERT INTO My_Table (user_id, meta_key) VALUES(33333, 'Sixpack');
INSERT INTO My_Table (user_id, meta_key) VALUES(33333, '54321');
INSERT INTO My_Table (user_id, meta_key) VALUES(22222, 'Marcel');
INSERT INTO My_Table (user_id, meta_key) VALUES(22222, 'Toulemonde');
INSERT INTO My_Table (user_id, meta_key) VALUES(22222, '00-33-9999');


== Works - gives first_name, last_name, phonenum - but as one column, not one row.


SET @user_id := 22222;
SELECT @ID := ID FROM My_Table WHERE user_id = @user_id;
SELECT * FROM
(  
  SELECT meta_key FROM My_Table WHERE ID = (@ID -2)
  UNION 
  SELECT meta_key FROM My_Table WHERE ID = (@ID -1)  
  UNION
  SELECT meta_key FROM My_Table WHERE ID = (@ID)  
) tab;


+------------+
| meta_key   |
+------------+
| Marcel     |
| Toulemonde |
| 00-33-9999 |
+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```